# How do I count the values from a pandas column which is a list of strings?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe column which is a list of strings:

```
df['colors']

0              ['blue','green','brown']
1              []
2              ['green','red','blue']
3              ['purple']
4              ['brown']
```

What I'm trying to get is:

```
'blue' 2
'green' 2
'brown' 2
'red' 1
'purple' 1
[] 1
```

Without knowing what I'm doing I even managed to count the characters in the entire column

```
b 5
[ 5
] 5
```

etc.

which I think was pretty cool, but the solution to this escapes me

Comment: `df['colors'].explode().value_counts()`?

Comment: Please post `df`.

Comment: https://www.w3resource.com/pandas/series/series-explode.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Solution

**Best option**: `df.colors.explode().dropna().value_counts()`.

However, if you also want to have counts for empty lists (`[]`), use **`Method-1.B/C`** similar to what was suggested by [Quang Hoang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4238408/quang-hoang) in the comments.

You can use any of the following two methods.

- **Method-1**: Use pandas methods alone ⭐⭐⭐

  > `explode --> dropna --> value_counts`
- **Method-2**: Use `list.extend --> pd.Series.value_counts`

```py
## Method-1
# A. If you don't want counts for empty []
df.colors.explode().dropna().value_counts() 

# B. If you want counts for empty [] (classified as NaN)
df.colors.explode().value_counts(dropna=False) # returns [] as Nan

# C. If you want counts for empty [] (classified as [])
df.colors.explode().fillna('[]').value_counts() # returns [] as []

## Method-2
colors = []
_ = [colors.extend(e) for e in df.colors if len(e)>0]
pd.Series(colors).value_counts()
```

**Output**:

```sh
green     2
blue      2
brown     2
red       1
purple    1
# NaN     1  ## For Method-1.B
# []      1  ## For Method-1.C
dtype: int64
```

### Dummy Data

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'colors':[['blue','green','brown'],
                             [],
                             ['green','red','blue'],
                             ['purple'],
                             ['brown']]})
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `Counter` + `chain`, which is meant to do exactly this. Then construct the Series from the Counter object.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

s = pd.Series([['blue','green','brown'], [], ['green','red','blue']])

pd.Series(Counter(chain.from_iterable(s)))
#blue     2
#green    2
#brown    1
#red      1
#dtype: int64
```

---

While `explode` + `value_counts` are the pandas way to do things, they're slower for shorter lists.

```
import perfplot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

def counter(s):
    return pd.Series(Counter(chain.from_iterable(s)))

def explode(s):
    return s.explode().value_counts()

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: pd.Series([['blue','green','brown'], [], ['green','red','blue']]*n), 
    kernels=[
        lambda s: counter(s),
        lambda s: explode(s),
    ],
    labels=['counter', 'explode'],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(17)],
    equality_check=np.allclose,  
    xlabel='~len(s)'
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Counter` from the `collections` module:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
from  itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame({'colors':[['blue','green','brown'],
                             [],
                             ['green','red','blue'],
                             ['purple'],
                             ['brown']]})

df = pd.Series(Counter(chain(*df.colors)))

print (df)
```

Output:

```
blue      2
green     2
brown     2
red       1
purple    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `.apply` with `pd.Series` to accomplish this:

```
# 1. Expand columns and count them
df_temp = df["colors"].apply(pd.Series.value_counts)

    blue    brown   green   purple  red
0   1.0 1.0 1.0 NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   1.0 NaN 1.0 NaN 1.0
3   NaN NaN NaN 1.0 NaN
4   NaN 1.0 NaN NaN NaN

# 2. Get the value counts from this:
df_temp.sum()

blue      2.0
brown     2.0
green     2.0
purple    1.0
red       1.0

# Alternatively, convert to a dict
df_temp.sum().to_dict()
# {'blue': 2.0, 'brown': 2.0, 'green': 2.0, 'purple': 1.0, 'red': 1.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution would be something like this I imagine.

You'd still have to add a condition to get the empty list, though.

```
colors = df.colors.tolist()
d = {}
for l in colors:
    for c in l:
        if c not in d.keys():
            d.update({c: 1})
        else:
            current_val = d.get(c)
            d.update({c: current_val+1})
```

this produces a dictionary looking like this:

```
{'blue': 2, 'green': 2, 'brown': 2, 'red': 1, 'purple': 1}
```